# SQLAlchemy: WITH new_values (id, field) as ( values (..., ...) )

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy core to create a query which hits only once the DB(postgres) and inserts a row if it's not already present.

Here is part of the query

```
WITH new_values (id, field) as (
  values 
     (1, 1),
     (2, 12),
     (3, 13),
     (4, 14)
)
INSERT INTO table1 (id, field)
SELECT id, field
FROM new_values
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
          FROM table1 as up 
          WHERE up.id = new_values.id);
```

I'm confused about:

- How do I create the CTE expression with the values specified (I only found examples with sub queries)
- How do I `SELECT 1` ?
- How do I add the where in the insert?

I'd like to use the core API and avoid direct execution.

PS:
The full query I would like to put in a single transaction is

```
WITH upsert AS (
   UPDATE table2
   SET field1=field1+1
   WHERE id=1234 AND field2=42
   RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO table2 (id, field1, field2)
SELECT 1234, 1, 42
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM upsert);

WITH new_values (id, field) as (
  values 
     (1, 1),
     (2, 12),
     (3, 13),
     (4, 14)
)
INSERT INTO table1 (id, field)
SELECT id, field
FROM new_values
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
          FROM table1 as up 
          WHERE up.id = new_values.id);
```

EDIT:
The model

```
table1 = Table('table1', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('field', Integer))

table2 = Table('table2', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('field1', Integer),
    Column('field2', Integer))
```

Comment: SQLAlchemy has the purpose of taking away the need to write SQL in OOP. They don't fit together well, but SQLAlchemy brings them together. It allows you to think in objects while working on a DB. If still think in SQL instead of models it is not the right tool to use.

Comment: Could you suggest how to obtain what I wrote with SQLAlchemy ORM in OOP then? I use ORMs on objects, but I don't know how to construct the specific query given the primitives SQLAlchemy offers. I'm pretty sure it can be done, I'm just missing a few pieces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Postgres syntax is not (yet) directly supported by SQLAlchemy. There is an issue filed -- several years ago, actually, but it has recent history and an increase in priority. See https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/2551/apparently-inserts-and-update-delete-can

Alternatively, `text()` items that  have `columns()` defined can have `cte()` called on them, so I thought for a while that this might work if the `update` were converted into plain sql with bind params. However, it is hard to get SQLAlchemy to correctly place the `with` at the top level of the query when the CTE is associated with a `select_from` of an `insert`. In short, until the above issue is resolved I think you are better off not trying to use this approach with SQLAlchemy core -- either use SQL or search for a different upsert method.

Comment: Thank you. I actually found that issue yesterday, so I ended up writing the query for the update and the insert with the core, compiled them and substituted into a string with the `WITH` part. To make it work I had to replace the SQL parameter `%(par_name)s` with the SQLAlchemy one `:par_name` in the compiled SQL, and then execute everything. The only bad thing was that I had to `CAST` in the SQL because I was using an enum type, and I was unable to make SQLAlchemy generate it for me.